# Betting system for blackjack in java: transferring a variable from another method

Tags: java

Rookie Java programmer here, I'm trying to make a betting system in Blackjack where I'm trying to transfer the 'bet' and 'cash' variables over to different methods. Here's a portion of my code that is in question:

```
class Player {
private ArrayList<Card>hand;
private String name;
static double cash, bet;

public Player(double theCash)
{
cash = theCash;
hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
bet = 0;
}
public static double wagerBet()
{Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Wager a bet: ");
double bet = in.nextDouble();
    cash = cash - bet;
    System.out.println("You wagered " + bet + ". " + "Now you have " + cash + " cash left.");
    return bet;
    }

public void rewardBet(double bet)
{
cash = cash + (bet * 2);
System.out.println("You now have " + cash + "cash.");
}
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish is I want my wagerBet method to subtract the user input amount from their total cash. First problem is that my wagerBet method isn't transferring the 'cash' variable from the Player method before it -- a similar problem occurs with transferring the 'bet' and 'cash' variables to my rewardBet method. Here's a run I did of my program so you can see what I mean:

```
Wager a bet: 50
You wagered 50.0. Now you have -50.0 cash left.
Your first card is Three of Diamonds
Your next card is Three of Hearts
Your total hand is currently 6.
Dealer showing King of Diamonds
Hit or Stay?hit
Your next card is Eight of Diamonds
Your total hand is currently 14.
Hit or Stay?hit
Your next card is Four of Hearts
Your total hand is currently 18.
Hit or Stay?stay
Dealer draws Six of Hearts
Dealer's total hand is currently 16.
Dealer draws Jack of Diamonds
Dealer's total hand is currently 26.
Dealer bust. You win.
You now have -50.0cash.
```

Before I say anything, I just want to establish that my program hardcodes the default cash total amount for the player to be 1000. So as you can see, the '1000' is not being counted at all, it SHOULD be 950 not -50. Second of all, the rewardBet method isn't working since it should've given me back my bet of 50 plus an additional 50 for winning, instead nothing happens and I stay at -50. I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that my variables aren't transferring over, I tried reading previous posts that were somewhat similar to my question but I can't seem to get my variables to be transferable to other methods.

Suggestions? Sorry for any vagueness, again I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can you construct an example that just focusses on what you want to ask (knowing that you're trying to write a betting system for blackjack isn't really applicable to the question, and the program doesn't need to contain this code), and is a complete, runnable problem (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? It's rather difficult to see what's going on here at the moment.

Comment: If you're dealing with instances, don't use static variables. You have an odd mix of instance and static stuff going on.

Comment: my wagerBet method isn't transferring over the cash variable from the player class. So for example if I set the initial cash amount for the player to be 1000, the wagerBet method will take the player's bet and subtract it from the total. Likewise with my rewardBet method, it isn't transferring over the total cash nor the bet that the player made initially. So I guess what I'm really asking is how to get my methods to 'share' or 'lend' each other variables?

Comment: And I KNOW  that it isn't transferring because in the example I included the bet is being subtracted from a value of 0 when it should be 1000 since that's the initial amount of money  that the player starts with. And similarly the rewardBet isn't giving me back my money when I win the round.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using static variables as attributes of the `Player` instance

A possible solution:

```
class Player {
    private ArrayList<Card>hand;
    private String name;
    private double cash, bet;

    public Player(double theCash)
    {
    cash = theCash;
    hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    bet = wagerBet();// here
    }
    public static double wagerBet()
    {Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Wager a bet: ");
    double bet = in.nextDouble();
        cash = cash - bet;
        System.out.println("You wagered " + bet + ". " + "Now you have " + cash + " cash left.");
        return bet;
        }

    public void rewardBet(double bet)
    {
    cash = cash + (bet * 2);
    System.out.println("You now have " + cash + "cash.");
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I did this initially but it just tells me that it can't make a static reference to the non-static field 'cash'. I'm assuming it just means that there's no variable within that method where cash is defined. The thing is I need for my wagerBet and rewardBet methods to take its cash variables from the Player class. I've no idea how.